# Stop setInterval() when a particular condition is encountered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to stop setInterval() when left margin is 1200px.
My code is :-

```
<html>
<body>
<script src="jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn').click(function () {
            var i = setInterval(function () {
                $('img').animate({
                    'margin-left': '+=100px'
                }, 'fast');
                var a = $('img').css('margin-left');
                if (a == "1200px") {
                      clearInterval(i);
                }
            }, 50);
        });
    });
</script>
<img src="48_800[1].jpg" height="50px" width="50px"><br>
<input type="button" value="start" id="btn"><br>
</body>
</html>
```

It is not working.Can anyone help me?

Comment: prepare a fiddle demo

Comment: That code looks fine? What exactly isn't working?

Comment: If a write anything under if() block then it does not get executed.Thats my main problem.

Comment: @user3298056 atleast explain why is `1200px` ? `.css()` returns you computed style so you cannot assume it to be `1200px`

Comment: I think you need to know [How to debug your JavaScript code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: Just make sure that the **intervalID** you use must be unique. Here you have used `i` which is pretty much common.

Answer (score 3):

You should cast to an integer the pixels value `a = parseInt(a);`. (as before you were obtaining values of `margin-left` with decimals, such as `99.45px` and then `199.45px` so it was jumping the `100px`)

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/jsXz9/1/)

```
var i = setInterval(function () {

    $('img').animate({
        'margin-left': '+=100px'
    }, 'fast');
    var a = $('img').css('margin-left');
    a = parseInt(a);
    if (a >= 100) {
        clearInterval(i);
    }
}, 50);
```

**Update**

---

I've just noticed the animation still running after the interval has been cleared. Not sure why is this happening but I found a way to solve the problem by caching the final margin in a variable rather than calculating it inside the animation.

[Live example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/jsXz9/2/)

Note that in the examples I'm using `>=100` to see the results.

Comment: I'm not sure that example is actually living? :)

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstand. I'm just being [facetious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/facetious). You would normally say "Live example". A living example imply's it has a life of it's own. +1 BTW!

Comment: @cesarandavisa you are right. With quotes is accepted. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead: [Updated](http://jsfiddle.net/qN4r7/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        var i = setInterval(function () {
            $('img').animate({
                'margin-left': '+=100px'
            }, 'fast');
            var a = $('img').css('margin-left');
            //console.log(a.substring(0,a.lastIndexOf('px')));
            if (a.substring(0,a.lastIndexOf('px')) >= 1200) {
                  clearInterval(i);
            }
        }, 50);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
if(parseInt(a) >= 1200)
{
     clearInterval(i);
}
},50);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btn').click(function () {
        var a="";
        while(a != "1200px"){
          $('img').animate({
                'margin-left': '+=100px'
            }, 'fast');
            a = $('img').css('margin-left');
      }
    });
});
```

your existing code looks erroneous ,besides referring to `SetInterval` is not required, the same could be achieved with decent while clause itself.

happy Coding :)

Answer (score 0):

try to change the value for the time into the setInterval method

the number value must to be in milliseconds